# Resolve warnings and make a library trimmable

Tags: .net

I have written a .NET library that converts between data types. It uses some reflection to analyse the types and find the best conversion between them. The code is [published here](https://github.com/ygoe/DeepConvert/tree/trimmable).

To make this library usable in an application that uses Trimming and AOT, I need to make this library trimmable. There is a [documentation about this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/prepare-libraries-for-trimming?pivots=dotnet-7-0) but it only covers the first steps and leaves me completely alone when it comes to resolving the warnings it has caused. I could resolve some of the warnings by adding attributes here and there. But the remaining warnings in the code are not covered by the documentation and seem to be unresolvable. The documentation for the attributes is close to non-existent. It completely fails to explain the consequences of adding such attributes to the code.

Does that mean that my library will never be usable in a trimmed application? How should I approach this problem? Can my library be rewritten so that it supports that scenario, even if some functionality may be lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection-based libraries are basically not trimmable, and *usually* aren't AOT compatible. Making such code work with AOT and trimming is *hard*. The main tool for migrating such is to use *generators* and switch the reflection work from runtime to build-time. Before .NET 8, this may require API changes - for example, having the *consumer* write the declaration half of a `partial` method, and have the *generator* write the *implementation* half - an example being the [regex generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-source-generators). The build tools in .NET 8 include a new feature - "interceptors" - that may allow existing reflection-based libraries to be made AOT-compatible *without* any changes to existing user-written application code, by having a generator detect all the uses of your library and emitting "interceptor" hooks that replace the calls to the library with AOT-friendly implementations. As an example, [here's some unit-test generator output from incomplete work to make Dapper AOT compatible](https://github.com/DapperLib/DapperAOT/blob/main/test/Dapper.AOT.Test/Interceptors/Execute.output.cs) (Dapper by itself is entirely incompatible with trimming/AOT; but the DapperAOT code generator fixes this)

The interceptor feature is discussed here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/interceptors.md - note that while it needs the new *build tools* in .NET 8, that **does not** mean that the feature itself requires .NET 8; as long as you have the up-to-date build tools, you can target any runtime version including .NET Framework.